# Merging updates in ASP.NET base template into customised websites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, versioning, visual-sourcesafe, branching-and-merging

We have an online shop/e-commerce website we developed in ASP.NET webforms with Visual Studio 2010 which we use as a template for building more shops. Each of our clients has slightly different requirements, and so we need to make customisations to the template, such as adding a field to a product, or adding new database tables relating to products.

We want to be able to make improvements to the template and propagate the changes to the customised websites built on it, whilst maintaining those customisations.

So far I have a couple of ideas:

1. Do a 'diff' on each customised website from the template and store as a patch for each site. When updating the template, just copy the template over all the customised sites and re-apply the patches. However, I'm not sure how we would handle version control, as each site is currently stored as a separate project in Visual SourceSafe.
2. Try to build the template in such a way as to allow customisations WITHOUT changes to the code or database. But I feel this would be quite difficult to achieve.

Does anyone have any better ideas, or suggestions on practical implementations?

Comment: If you need to do ongoing development/maintenance (and it sounds like you do), you want option 2.  It's only difficult when you don't factor in the difficulty of maintaining 'N' separate copies of your code.

Comment: Do you think about moving away from VSS as option?

Comment: @Gus There are some problems I see as being feasible to solve this way. For instance, adding an extra field to a product - I can just store it in some "meta data" column. However, then I lose the ability to query the database on the new field. But what about adding more complex customisation... for instance, "product ranges" which are collections of related products, being distinct from "product categories". How could something that requires a whole new SQL table possibly be implemented this way...?

Comment: @LazyBadger Yes we're in the process of moving to TFS

Comment: @bombastic - well, it's your choice... but branches will be usable even in TFS

Comment: @LazyBadger So basically every time I do a custom site, I create a new branch, then if I update the template, I merge the original back into every branch? Thanks!

Comment: @bombastic - well, yes, common workflow will be like you wrote

Comment: @bombastic typically you take your most-complex cases, implement support for them, and then also add configuration properties to "turn off" use of such a feature if some customers don't want it.  By the way, enabling those features can become a revenue stream/licensed features.